# Breeze, database first and anonymous objects

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, breeze

I'm using the ASP.Membership provider and I've created an additional table for the user data.  I'm only experimenting and I'm not worried about security or anything like that.  I'm only concerned with the big picture.

I'm experimenting with Breeze, SPA, Entity Framework, and Web.API and perhaps I'm rushing in too fast before I'm getting a good grasp on the individual concepts.

My Breeze query looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<object> Users()
{
    return (
        from user in _contextProvider.Context.Users
        join membership in _contextProvider.Context.Memberships on user.UserId equals membership.UserId
        join userProfile in _contextProvider.Context.UserProfiles on user.UserId equals userProfile.UserId
        select new { user, membership, userProfile}
    );
}
```

My results looks like this (only first record shown):

```
{
$id: "1",
$type: "<>f__AnonymousType4`3[[SPA01.EntityFramework.User, SPA01],[SPA01.EntityFramework.Membership, SPA01],[SPA01.EntityFramework.UserProfile, SPA01]], SPA01",
user: {
    $id: "2",
    $type: "SPA01.EntityFramework.User, SPA01",
    UserId: "dd59fcd1-9d88-4494-a37c-1c25155cb77d",
    ApplicationId: "23042eba-1113-4e56-8ac6-4640120ecc6c",
    UserName: "DHaworth",
    IsAnonymous: false,
    LastActivityDate: "2014-02-17T00:01:39.707",
    Membership: {
        $id: "3",
        $type: "SPA01.EntityFramework.Membership, SPA01",
        UserId: "dd59fcd1-9d88-4494-a37c-1c25155cb77d",
        ApplicationId: "23042eba-1113-4e56-8ac6-4640120ecc6c",
        Password: "sdfasdfsadfsadfsafasfae0dfzT64vo=",
        PasswordFormat: 1,
        PasswordSalt: "/CRUMPNf9+byEdPraeasfsaQJw==",
        Email: "MyEmail@hotmail.com",
        PasswordQuestion: "TR",
        PasswordAnswer: "B4HOezQ/TYasdfasfasfgjz4oAOERhnc=",
        IsApproved: true,
        IsLockedOut: false,
        CreateDate: "2014-01-04T05:18:18.063",
        LastLoginDate: "2014-02-17T00:01:39.707",
        LastPasswordChangedDate: "2014-01-12T21:58:30.497",
        LastLockoutDate: "1754-01-01T00:00:00.000",
        FailedPasswordAttemptCount: 0,
        FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart: "1754-01-01T00:00:00.000",
        FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount: 0,
        FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowsStart: "1754-01-01T00:00:00.000",
        Comment: null,
        User: {
            $ref: "2"
        }
    },
    UserProfile: {
            $id: "4",
            $type: "SPA01.EntityFramework.UserProfile, SPA01",
            UserId: "dd59fcd1-9d88-4494-a37c-1c25155cb77d",
            FirstName: "Duane",
            LastName: "Haworth",
            User: {
            $ref: "2"
            }
    },
    Roles: [ ]
},
membership: {
        $ref: "3"
},
userProfile: {
        $ref: "4"
}
```

},

I'm creating a User Admin screen where I'm going to display the information from all three tables.

Can I do this while still using Breeze using JsonResultsAdapter or do I need to do something on the Entity Framework side first?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Breeze supports this scenario (wrapping entities in an anonymous object) out of the box; no extra work required.  See the [lookup lists example](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/lookup-lists), for instance.  The Breeze client needs to have the metadata to handle the entities, but that's no problem if you're using EF and the `EFContextProvider`.